# How to do or gate operation in javascript

Tags: javascript, binary

I am doing a hacker rank problem.

```
function or(a, b){return (a || b);}

function acmTeam(topic) {
  var arr = topic;

  for(var i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
    var iItem = arr[i];

    for(var j=i+1; j<arr.length; j++) { 
      var jItem = arr[j];
      var orItem = or(iItem, jItem);

      console.log(iItem);
      console.log(jItem);
      console.log('----');
      console.log(orItem);
      console.log();
    } 
  }

}

var topic = [ '10101', '11100', '11010', '00101' ];
var out = acmTeam(topic);
```

I copied the or gate operation from [here](https://codepen.io/cassiecodes/pen/XNvNrw?editors=0010)

I think I got something like this. It seems not what I expected as an or gate operation. Any idea?

```
10101
11100
----
10101

10101
11010
----
10101

10101
00101
----
10101

11100
11010
----
11100

11100
00101
----
11100

11010
00101
----
11010
```

Comment: what goes wrong? which results do you expect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First convert the string variables to base 2 variables using parseInt , and then perform bitwise OR operation.

The result would be in base 10 form. So convert again to base 2 using toString(2)

```
   function or(a, b){return (parseInt(a, 2) | parseInt(b,2)).toString(2);}
```

```js
function or(a, b){return (parseInt(a, 2) | parseInt(b,2)).toString(2);}

function acmTeam(topic) {
  var arr = topic;

  for(var i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
var iItem = arr[i];

for(var j=i+1; j<arr.length; j++) { 
  var jItem = arr[j];
  var orItem = or(iItem, jItem);

  console.log(iItem);
  console.log(jItem);
  console.log('----');
  console.log(orItem);
  console.log();
} 
  }

}

var topic = [ '10101', '11100', '11010', '00101' ];
var out = acmTeam(topic);
```